# I get corrupted files with Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

I get corrupted files with Apache POI.

I am heard that this will be a out of memory problem.

Or is it problem with JVM that is Oracle OpenJDK 7?

Comment: How are they corrupted? What exceptions (if any) do you get? What errors do you get when opening them? Are you in fact running out of memory?

Comment: Application do not trace any errors.

Comment: In my dedicated server wher is 4Gb RAM and Intel Zeon Quad Core has no problems but on my Virtual Private Server where is 2Gb ram has this problem.